# I need to generate a group of random numbers between 97 and 122

Tags: c, random

I have to generate random numbers between 97 and 122 using a specific algorithm but I get numbers that are greater than 122. Here is the code:

```
srand( time (NULL));

int num;
unsigned i;

for (i = 0;i<100;i++){

    num = 97+(rand()%122);

        printf("%d\n",num );

}

return 0;
```

Comment: `rand()%122` generates values ranging from 0 to 121. So maximum possible value of `num` would be 121+97 = 218.

Answer (score 9):

To get the *random* numbers between 97 and 122, inclusive, in your code

```
 num = 97+(rand()%122);
```

should be

```
 num = 97+(rand()%26);
```